# Write a function that uses lookup types on generics

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-types

I want to write a function that does three things:

- operates on a generic type T
- accepts a key: K of T where T[K] must be a boolean
- assigns a value to T[K]

I'm following [this guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) which hints at this possibility:

```
type FunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never }[keyof T];
type FunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, FunctionPropertyNames<T>>;

type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
type NonFunctionProperties<T> = Pick<T, NonFunctionPropertyNames<T>>;

interface Part {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    subparts: Part[];
    updatePart(newName: string): void;
}

type T40 = FunctionPropertyNames<Part>;  // "updatePart"
type T41 = NonFunctionPropertyNames<Part>;  // "id" | "name" | "subparts"
type T42 = FunctionProperties<Part>;  // { updatePart(newName: string): void }
type T43 = NonFunctionProperties<Part>;  // { id: number, name: string, subparts: Part[] }
```

However, it seems that I can only accomplish my goal if my function operates on concrete types. To compute the boolean property names of T, I've modified the first line from the example like this:

```
type BoolPropNames<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

It works if I use a concrete type:

```
class Thing {
  isGreat: boolean;
}

function assignToThing(thing: Thing, key: BoolPropNames<Thing>) {
  thing[key] = false;
}
```

But if I try to operate on a generic, it doesn't:

```
function assign<T>(thing: T, key: BoolPropNames<T>) {
  thing[key] = false;
}
```

When I try to do this, TypeScript gives me the following error:

```
(parameter) key: { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? K : never; }[keyof T]
Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? K : never; }[keyof T]]'.ts(2322)
```

Why doesn't TypeScript allow me to operate on generics this way, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

TS is not able to compute the result of `BoolPropNames<T>` as it is computed when `T` is given, differently then in previous examples where you had no type variable, but some specific type. As for example `BoolPropNames<Thing>` is computed into `isGreat` and `thing[key]` is known as to be `boolean`.

`BoolPropNames<T>` cannot be computed before so it does not know that result will be a key which gives us `boolean`. And if it doesn't know that `think[key]` is boolean then you cannot assign to it boolean.

In order to fix this, we can for example apply argument which will be considered as `T[K]` type. Then TS doesn't need to compute the type, as it will always be value of type at the given key. Consider following code:

```
function assign<T, K extends BoolPropNames<T>>(thing: T, key: K, value: T[K]) {
  thing[key] = value;
}
assign({ a: true }, 'a', false);
```

---

If third argument does not satisfy you, and you just want to set any value without putting it as argument we can also do some partial application in order to create such behavior. Consider:

```
// function which creates assign function
const createAssign = <T, K extends BoolPropNames<T> = BoolPropNames<T>>
(value: T[K]) => (thing: T, key: K) => {
  thing[key] = value;
}
// below assign function is created for type `Example`
type Example = { a: boolean };
const assign = createAssign<Example>(false); 
assign({a: true}, 'a');
```

By partial application we have created `assign` function which works in the same way your original one was working, so it is assigning `false` into only `boolean` fields. By this way you can make all such functions.

Of course the downside is that we need to generate such for every type by setting generic type variable, so it is not so polymorphic as solution with different order of arguments.

Comment: But it does know that the key will give us boolean: `T[K] extends boolean ? K : never`

Comment: It even not computes that until type variable is given. So it does not analyse this type definitions at this level. So it doesn't know

Comment: The core to understand is to see BoolPropNames as a function which has no annotation of the output. It means that until we will execute it until we don't know what it will return. TS is not computing it and it is visible also in the error you see, TS just puts you the whole definition as it doesn't know what it will be finally

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Although it seems to me that TS should assume that it will work for any T that has boolean properties! It shouldn't complain unless I actually call assign with a T and a K where T[K] is not a boolean.